# Why can't we cast as generic type if the supplied type has implicit conversion available?

Tags: c#, casting, implicit-conversion, generic-type-argument

I've looked around for some time now and can't seem to find a direct answer to my question.

---

I am creating (as an exercise, self induced, not homework) a basic `Cast<T>` method, where an `object` is supplied and if the conversion is valid then `T` is returned. The initial method was incredibly straight forward. Simply perform implicit conversion and return the result.

```
internal T Cast<T>(object val) => (T)val;
```

My thinking here was that this would either work or it would throw an exception at runtime. Well, it does throw an exception at runtime, which I expect to happen due to attempting to cast `string` to `int` for example.

However, what I didn't expect, is for it to fail to cast `int` to `double` or vice-versa. I can do this when explicitly stating types:

```
int a = 0;
double b = 0;
a = (int)b;
b = (double)a;
```

All of that works fine and throws no exceptions and from my understanding this is by design for the same reason that `char` to `string` works. The types are similar in which only their ranges are different. Per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/int):

> `int` - -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
>
> `double` - ±5.0 × 10^−324 to ±1.7 × 10^308

Thus casting from `double` to `int` caps the value to `int.MaxValue` or `MinValue` respectively. For example, the following code will print `int.MinValue` both times:

```
int a = int.MaxValue;
double b = double.MaxValue;
a = (int)b;
Console.WriteLine($"int: {a}");
b = (double)a;
Console.WriteLine($"double: {b});
```

---

This makes me curious, is there a reason why we can't cast from `object` to `T` when our `object` is of type `int` and our `T` is of type `double` or is this just a .NET shortfall?

Comment: [Boxing and Unboxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing)

Comment: Not really an answer so I'll keep it to a comment, but you should do something like `public TOut Cast<TIn, TOut>(TIn val) => (TOut)val;`. Prevents these issues and the needless boxing / casting to object

Comment: @John That won't compile.  The compiler won't know if the conversion is valid, so it won't allow it.  The only way to make it compile is to box the value (or not write such a method in the first place).

Comment: @Servy not sure how on earth I didn't think that, sorry.

Comment: @Servy The method is more of an exercise prior to writing a method with explicit casting later similar to `DataRow.Field<T>(string)`. It turns out that `SqlDataReader` doesn't offer such a method, and my product lead is considering implementing an extension method that offers such functionality. I just wanted to understand more of it myself.

Comment: @Servy so that I ensure I understand; based on the answer in the other question, I have to perform type-checking and return explicit casts in order for something like this to work?

Comment: @PerpetualJ You need to unbox the value into a variable of the type it actually is, and then convert it into whatever you want it to be turned into, or use an operation that knows how to do that dynamically at runtime (which is going to be *very* expensive; you almost certainly don't want to do that in a situation like this).

Comment: You have to keep in mind those casts work differently. if you cast an int to a double to compiler is smart enough to understand you actually want to convert the value (this can be seen if you convert 2.5 to an int you'll get the value 2, so it actually changes) now the  cast in your cast function does no conversion, it tells to look at the object val as if it where an object of type T which doesn't work since a double is not an int. Even though they both represent numbers they store data in different ways